# mongoDB project array element after filter

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following (simplified) aggregation:

```
Model.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'orders',
        localField: '_id',
        foreignField: 'customer',
        as: 'orders',
      },
    },
    {
      $project: {
        openOrders: {
          $filter: {
            input: '$orders',
            as: 'order',
            cond: { $eq: ['$$order.status', 'open'] },
          },
        },
      },
    },        
  ])
```

which returns the following:

```
{
  _id: ...,
  openOrders: [
    [Object], [Object]
  ],
}
```

Those `[Object]`'s are simply the returned objects, persisted in the database, with all their fields.

I don't find a way to project/filter out those objects' fields and instead return only their `_id`'s:

```
{
  _id: ...,
  openOrders: [
    _id: ...,
    _id: ....
  ],
}
```

EDIT: I'd rather prefer the following expected output:

```
{
  _id: ...,
  openOrders: [
    { _id: ... },
    { _id: ... }
  ],
}
```

I tried adding a new `$project` stage at various points of the aggregation with no success. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a `$project` stage like below:

```js
{
  $project: {
    openOrders: 'openOrders._id'
  }
}
```

This will give the output like:

```
{
  _id: ...,
  openOrders: [
    _id1,
    _id2,
    ...
  ],
}
```

instead of

```
{
  _id: ...,
  openOrders: [
    _id: ...,
    _id: ....
  ],
}
```

I suggest this type of querying because, if you actually see `openOrders`, it's just the array of `_id`s, so adding only one `_id` field inside the array doesn't make sence.

If you still want the output to be like the array of object, then you can use the below:

```js
{
  $project: {
    'openOrders._id': 1
  }
}
```

Comment: After the first $project? Something like: ```{ $project { ... } }, { $project{ ‘openOrders._id’: 1 } }```?

Comment: Nope, like... `.aggregate([{ $lookup: {...}}, { $project: {...}}, { $project{ openOrders: 'openOrders._id'}}])`.

Comment: I tried but it still gives me the array of ```[Object]```'s instead of the array of ```_id```s. Let me check the other answer as well. However, thank you for the time.

Comment: Could yo try to run this in Mongo shell and check?

Comment: Sorry, your answer was correct! I was printing wrong, but thanks to @whoami suggestion, I could verify the correctness of your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Ohh, I was not aware that you were JSON with objects. Well, no worries, each day we learn new things.

Answer (score 1):

As you need an array of `_id`'s like this

```
openOrders: [ _id: ..., _id: .... ]
```

but not an array of `_id`'s in objects :

```
openOrders: [ {_id: ...}, {_id: ....} ]
```

You need to use [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html#reduce-aggregation) instead of `$filter` :

**Try below query :**

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
    {
      $project: {
        openOrders: {
          $reduce: {
            input: "$orders", // Same like `$filter` use reduce to iterate on array
            initialValue: [], // consider an initial value
            in: { // If condition is met, push value to array else return holding array as is.
              $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$$this.status", "open" ] },
                { $concatArrays: [ "$$value", [ "$$this._id" ] ] },
                "$$value"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iAE602ZwyuL)

**Note :** In javaScript - if you're printing a JSON with objects, you need to print it with `JSON.stringify(yourJSON)` - which makes it a string, So that you don't see `[Object], [Object]` in console rather you would see actual objects.

**Update :**

If you need an array of objects with `_id` field just add another `$project` stage at the end, but I would highly suggest to use `$reduce` and get an array for your scenario :

```
{ $project: { "openOrders._id": 1 } } // which would just extract `_id` fields in each objects
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mXuAGYzPwJP)

Comment: Actually, the example of the expected output in my question is not strict, but can also be an array of objects, each containing an ```_id``` field. I'll edit my question, and if you can also edit your answer to match my new request, I'll really appreciate.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. With that suggestion about the way of printing the objects, I could verify that the first answer to my question was correct and enough for solving my problem. I accepted the other answer just for a matter of timing, anyway your answer provides interesting insights on this matter, and from it I can learn new things. Thanks for your time. Appreciate it!

Comment: May I ask you why you suggest to use ```$reduce``` and get array of ```_id``` instead of an array of objects? Could be for a matter of convenience when handling the returned result?

Comment: @Kenna : Yes, you don't get data from DB just to look at it :-) You'll definitely handle it at some point, So think of it as you just need `_id`'s do you just get them in an array :: `[_id1, _id2]` or do you get them in objects of an array `[{_id : 1}, {_id : 1}]` - I would say an array of `_id`'s suits the best for most of the scenarios ! But at the end it all depends on your requirement though ! Just remember getting data right from DB, can help you a lot in code..

Comment: Thank you. Yes of course I will handle them later, I was wondering the differences in the usage. Actually, I'll be fine with both the representations, I just need to adapt the receiver of these data, handling an array of objects or a simple array of ```_id```'s. What do you mean with 'getting data from DB can help you in code'? Sorry for asking a lot, just want to understand :-)

Comment: @Kenna : I'm mean data in proper format, transform the way you need if possible & quick in DB get it done there itself..

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thank you